# Line Break in (Multi-Line) Buttons

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

How can I have the title of a react-native-elements' button split into multiple lines?

```js
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
....
// The \n in the following statement does NOT work! 
<Button
    title="Creating a Shift \n(and inviting employees)"
    onPress={ () => {
        console.log("Button Pressed");
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose the title's text in curly braces.

```js
<Button
    title={"Creating a Shift \n(and inviting employees)"}
    onPress={ () => {
        console.log("Button Pressed");
    }}
/>
```